# Carrega o id no hidden usando autocomplete

Tags: javascript

Olá,
tenho o seguinte script, autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".nomeCliente").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/PreVenda/CarregarCliente",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { nome_razao: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.nome_razao,
                                    value: item.nome_razao,
                                    id: item.id
                                };
                                $("id_cliente").val(data.id);
                            }))

                        }
                    })
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar o ID em um hidden

Comment: Você quer colocar o id do item selecionado ou todos?

Comment: Na hora que seleciono o item, ele carrega o ID do item selecionado no hidden

Comment: Esse `$("id_cliente")` seria o quê? Para alem desse seletor estar errado (falta `.` ou `#`) ele nunca é corrido pois tem um `return` antes. Podes mostrar o HTML que tens e explicar melhor o que queres que aconteça?

Comment: eu preciso na hora que seleciono no meu textbox o nome do cliente, ele automaticamente jogue o ID do cliente em um Hidden eu usei  $("#id_cliente").val(data.id); mas não consigo coloca o ID do cliente no hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o evento [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) para isso. Veja um exemplo básico abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nomeCliente").autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY";
      suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);
      $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
          url: suggestURL
        })
        .success(function(data) {
          response(data[1]);
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui)
      $("#id_cliente").val(ui.item.value);
    },
    messages: {
      noResults: "sasa",
      results: "sasas"
    }
  });
});
```

[Veja funcionando no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pzynrvwk/1/)

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudo muito !!!